# Why my method of calculating of the area of a circle doesn't work?

Tags: integration, circles

I want to manually calculate the area of a circle using integration.
I assume that the circle is divided into many triangles (the number of triangles approaching infinity).
The area of a single triangle would be:
$$S_t=\frac{1}{2}r^2sin\theta$$
Where $S_t$ is the area, $r$ is the equal sides of the isosceles triangle and $\theta$ is the angle between those sides and is approaching zero.
Therefore the area of a circle should be:
$$S=\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{1}{2}r^2sin\theta\space\Delta\theta=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{2}r^2sin\theta\space d\theta=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}r^2\int_0^{2\pi}sin\theta\space d\theta=-\frac{1}{2}r^2cos\theta$$
But it's not even close to the actual formula of the area of a circle $\pi r^2$.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You seem to have mixed up "$\theta$" and "$d\theta$." The "width" of a single wedge is $d\theta$; $\theta$ would be the direction that that wedge is pointing, which is irrelevant to its area. (Also you didn't actually plug in your bounds at the end, but that's not the fundamental error.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\theta$ is varying, it certainly shouldn't be ending up in your final expression. The first error is in your second equality: it is in no way the case that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{i=0}^n\frac{1}{2}r^2\sin\theta\Delta\theta = \int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{2}r^2\sin\theta\mathrm{d}\theta - $$ where does the $2\pi$ come from, for starters? It's also not clear what exactly you mean by $\Delta\theta$ here - $\theta$ is already a small angle. Instead, note that nothing actually depends on $i$, so in fact $$\sum\limits_{i=0}^n\frac{1}{2}r^2\sin\theta = \frac{1}{2}nr^2\sin\theta.$$

To actually calculate the area of a circle using your decomposition:

First, let's just note that $\theta$ is precisely $\frac{2\pi}{n}$, and just replace it with that. Thus, the area of each triangle in your $n$th step is $$S_t(n) = \frac{1}{2}r^2\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right),$$ so the total area in the $n$th step is $$S(n) = \frac{1}{2}r^2n\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right).$$

We can now use the Taylor series for $\sin$ to simplify this:

$$\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right) = \frac{2\pi}{n} + O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right).$$

Thus, $$S(n) = \frac{1}{2}r^2\left(2\pi + O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right),$$

which converges to $\pi r^2$ as $n \to \infty$, as expected.

Comment: Using $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\sin(x)/x = 1$ also works if the asker isn't familiar with taylor series yet.